# How to view and search in SVG on GNU/Linux in a good way?

Tags: linux, svg

There are already some more or less generic like (Eye of Gnome) and specialized (rsvg-display) viewers that work on Linux. I find them not good enough hovewer, especially for viewing big things like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Linux_Distribution_Timeline.svg).

Are there any SVG viewers that satisfy the following:

- Convenient zooming and panning;
- Searching for text in svg;
- Quick: coarse mode when zooming/panning, fine mode when settled; avoiding full rendering when only part of the image is visible; caching;
- Nice to have: FireBug-like debugger.

I tried the following:

- rsvg-display: not convenient zooming, not so fast, no searching;
- inkview: too simple, no zooming, no searching;
- firefox: can't zoom SVGs even though it can scale regular pictues;
- eog: rasterizes before viewing, slow, no searching;
- gpicview: rasterizes before viewing, fast enough; scaling not convenient, no searching;

Comment: You wrote: "firefox: can't zoom SVGs even though it can scale regular pictures". My experience (for quite a few months at least and with whatever version of Firefox current at the time) is that firefox does zoom SVGs quite nicely. You may have to go into `about:config` and search for "zoom". Then, you can set the zoom increments and the maximum zoom. A plus is that the images are not rasterized. (I search for text in svg files using a text editor.)

Comment: @vasa1, Looks like I had "zoom text only" set. Strange that it still has effect even if I opened an image directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried Google Chrome or Chromium? They can zoom, are fast (at least with the example svg you linked above), have search and built firebug like in developer tools that even let you edit and save files locally.

Comment: BTW right now reading an a [document](http://www.hgi.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/media/hgi/veroeffentlichungen/2011/10/19/svgSecurity-ccs11.pdf) about SVG security. One of tricks is to ~"lure user to save SVG file (to be opened with a browser as file:// instead of image viewer)".

Comment: Chrome is a fast way to open SVG in a new tab, however there are certain SVG files that Chrome doesn't zoom